# Add class 'active' in AJAX Pagination

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, pagination

I have a pagination, and my pagination is not using any plugin, I just create it by myself. But, I have a problem, how can I give a `class='active'` when the button is clicked. I just using function in my pagination. Please help, thank you.

Comment: Show us some code, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click','your-element-class', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

When the element is clicked, if it already has the `active` class, it will be removed; otherwise it will be added.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit?

Comment: When he click on the element he want to set class active, this will verify if that element have the class active, if yes, remove, if no, add the class.

Comment: Thanks, edited with some explanation. Answers with only code and no explanation often get flagged in the review queues.

Comment: no no no, I using function like function foo_bar(){}